# I want to take multiple cells, and what ever cell is not FALSE I want that cell to be extracted and moved to another column in a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I am working on an action form. There are actions that can be ticked by boxes. If the boxes are not ticked they leave the cell with a value FALSE. I want any cell (B6,B7,E7) to be copied to a different cell if the cell does not read FALSE.

I am attempting this on google sheets script editor with an if statement.

```
var submit_type_range = submit_sheet.getRange('B6:B7');
  var types =submit_type_range.getValues();

  if (types != 'FALSE')
   var type = types 
   return type 



  var type_submitted = log_sheet.getRange(lastRow_log+1,3)
  type_submitted.setValue(type)
```

I know this won't work but I expected at least type to extract all cells that do not display FALSE.

Comment: `types` is a two dimensional array.  `submit_sheet` is not defined. `log_sheet` is not defined. `lastRow_log` is not defined.  You should try a couple of tutorials before writing your own script.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want to do we had to rewrite almost the full function; we apologize if the following code doesn't meet your expectations.

The code will first read the values of the cells B6, B7 and E7. As `.getValues()` A1 notation only works for continuous cells, we are going to concatenate the E7 data to the others cells.

After that we are going to iterate each cell and check if its content is *false* or not. We wrote it in lower case because it's a [reserved keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word), so every *FALSE* get converted to *false* in our reading array.

Finally, we write the data of those cells on the last empty row. As we didn't understand which column of the last empty row you want the data in, we choose to write each cell in the column that match the index of the original reading (i.e. B6  Column A, B7  Column B and E7  Column C).

As an extra, we made one last loop that deletes the elements of the `types` array which are *false*. We added this because of your last phrase.

```
function falseRemover() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('{SPREADSHEET ID}').getSheetByName(
    'Sheet1');
  var types = spreadsheet.getRange('B6:B7').getValues().concat(spreadsheet
    .getRange('E7').getValues());
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  var columnIterator = 0;
  for (var cell in types) {
    columnIterator++;
    if (types[cell] != 'false') {
      spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, columnIterator).setValue(types[cell]);
    }
  }

  for (var cell in types) {
    if (types[cell] == 'false') {
      types[cell].pop();
    }
  }
}
```

We hope that this code example is useful to you, but don't hesitate to ask for more help if you need it.